# Setting firstDay for FullCalendar not working

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, primeng

I'm using Angular 2 and PrimeNG's Schedule, which uses FullCalendar. I want the first day of the week to be Monday, but I think my code must be slightly off. I added `[locale]="en"` to my p-schedule element, as seen below:

```
<p-schedule [events]="events" [header]="headerConfig" (onEventClick)="handleEventClick($event)" [fixedWeekCount]="false" [locale]="en"></p-schedule>
```

Then in my component file. I added the following:

```
this.en = {
    firstDay: 1
}
```

After these changes, my first day is still Sunday. I'm not getting any errors, but it just isn't working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Might have jumped the gun here (therefore deleted answer at least for now) But try with `firstDayOfWeek`, if that would work, even though it *seems* that `firstDay` would be the correct way. Never hurts to try tho :D

Comment: I replaced first day with firstDayOfWeek and it still isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

component.ts:

```
option: Object;

ngOnInit() {
  this.option = {
    firstDay: 1
  };
}
```

component.html:

```
<p-schedule [options]="option"></p-schedule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the locale for p-calendar. I moved `firstDayOfWeek: 1` to the end of the array and it worked:

```
    this.nl = {
        dayNames: ["Zondag", "Maandag", "Dinsdag", "Woensdag", "Donderdag", "Vrijdag", "Zaterdag"],
        dayNamesShort: ["Zo", "Ma", "Di", "Wo", "Do", "Vr", "Za"],
        dayNamesMin: ["Zo", "Ma", "Di", "Wo", "Do", "Vr", "Za"],
        monthNames: ["Januari", "Februari", "Maart", "April", "Mei", "Juni", "Juli", "Augustus", "September", "Oktober", "November", "December"],
        monthNamesShort: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "Mei", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Okt", "Nov", "Dec"],
        firstDayOfWeek: 1
    };
```

This is my html:

```
<p-calendar id="entityActiveSince" [showIcon]="true" [locale]="nl"
 dateFormat="dd-mm-yy" [readonlyInput]="true" [disabled]="saving"   
 [(ngModel)]="entity.ActiveSince" [monthNavigator]="true" 
 [yearNavigator]="true" yearRange="1990:2020" name="activeSince"></p-calendar>
```

Comment: Did you do your html the same way I did? So in your case, did you have [locale]="nl" in your p-calendar? By the way, I'm using Schedule, not Calendar, so my element is p-schedule. Not sure if it makes a difference.

Comment: I updated my post and added the HTML we're using. I don't think the Schedule component works differently then the Calendar component regarding translations.